# How can I add a reset button on a flash file?

Tags: actionscript-3, reset

How can I make a reset button so when the file ends it resets all variables and code to the default run-time code and frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a button to the stage on the last frame (or where you want to), let's say "resetButton_mc".

```
resetButton_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     //Reset all variables and send the playhead to the appropriate frame
};
```

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: I want a real reset. Not a function!

Comment: There is no "real reset" mate in AS, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Make a button instance, say resetBtn

```
resetBtn.onRelease = function(){
    //manually reset each variable
        userName = "";
        userAge = 0;
        .
        .
        .

        }
```

This still uses a function though.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there is no real reset method within the Flash Player. Depending on the complexity of the project, setting every property and variable back to their defaults may not be manageable.

If this is the case you might want to consider two options:

Wrap your code in a class which has an additional 'deconstruct' method. The deconstruct method should look after eventlisteners and what not. The constructor should call a method like init to setup all the variables. This way your not doubling up code.

For example:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class Foo extends EventDispatcher {

        private var _a:String;

        public function Foo()  {
            init();
        }   

        public function init():void {
            _a = "Default Value";
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
        }

        public function deconstruct():void {
            // Clean up time
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
        }

        private function onEnter(e:Event):void {
            trace("frame");
        }

        public function get a():String { return _a; }       
        public function set a(value:String):void { _a = value; }
    }
}
```

Then on your main timeline

```
var foo:Foo = new Foo();

resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    foo.deconstruct();
    foo = new Foo();
}
```

This ensures you are truly resetting

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(stage.LoaderInfo.url), '_level0');
}
```

This above code will reload your swf file